# Improve performance on view cross join unique values(Scalability)

Tags: oracle

I'm using Oracle APEX as my database. My data is stored in tables(i.e. table1), and I use views to run some kind of scoring system (table1=>view1), the views take less than a second to be displayed on screen. Then I need to perform a cross join in order to get all possible permutations in the data set, given that attrib1 from all views must be different from one another. I have 18 tables and 18 views with records ranging between 2 and 31(this means a lot of permutations)

Below you an find a code snippet for a parcial view with 4 views, which takes very little time to process.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "parcial_view" ("col_1", "col_2", "col_3", "col_4", "total") AS 
  SELECT 
 view1.attrib1 as col_1
,view2.attrib1 as col_2
,view3.attrib1 as col_3
,view4.attrib1 as col_4
,view1.attrib2+view2.attrib2+view2.attrib2+view4.attrib2 as total
from view1
cross join view2
cross join view3
cross join view4
where (view1.attrib1 not in (view2.attrib1, view3.attrib1, view4.attrib1)
and view2.attrib1 not in (view3.attrib1, view4.attrib1)
and view3.attrib1 not in (view4.attrib1))
or 'empty' in (view1.attrib1, view2.attrib1, view3.attrib1, view4.attrib1)
order by total desc
```

However, when I use all 18 views, I get the ORA-00040: Active Time Limit Exceeded - Call Aborted. So I'm looking for ways to improve this approach performance-wise.

Comment: `this means a lot of permutations` - let say there are only 3 record on average from each of these 18 tables, so the database must generate 3^18=387 420 489 rows - this *must* take a lot of time!  Please explain why are so many records generated? What is a business requirement ? No human being can read that amount of data.

Comment: I only want to read the top score, but i must ensure that all permutations are calculated. I tried using "fetch first row only" but it didnt actually work. I will come back once i try to generate the records without the where clause, which I believe is the time consuming part